# for loop for changing the text

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

My question is that I want to change the text by clicking button. I have three words and I want to change the text three times by replacing it from the words. I have run loop for it. But loop is not runing propely. Please help me.

```js
function myfunction() {
    var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var a = ["Ammar","Bilal","Ali"];
    for (var i = 0; i<a.length;){
        div.innerHTML = a[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <p id="mydiv"></p>
    <button onclick="myfunction()">next</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Please share your code or jsfiddle link for proper help.

Comment: You will likely run into DOM updating slower than your loop. Use a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) or [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead of a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` to show each words without using for loop.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  var a = ["Ammar", "Bilal", "Ali"];
  let i = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {

    div.innerHTML = a[i];
    i++;
    if (i == 3) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="mydiv"></p>
  <button onclick="myfunction()">next</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why would you run the function every time you click the button? And because you do, you need to clear the interval

Comment: Because I want to make quiz app with js.